# Convert ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> to List<List<Integer>>

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have my Integer data in Array Lists of Arrays Lists and I want to convert that data to Lists of List format.
How can I do it?

```
public List<List<Integer>> subsetsWithDup(int[] nums) {

    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> ansList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

    String arrStr = nums.toString();
    ArrayList<Integer> tempList = null;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < arrStr.length()-1 ; i++){
        for(int j = i+1 ; j<arrStr.length() ; j++){

            tempList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            tempList.add(Integer.parseInt(arrStr.substring(i,j)));

        }

        if(!ansList.contains(tempList)){
            ansList.add(tempList);
        }

    }
    return ansList;
}
```

Comment: `List` is the base class of `ArrayList`,so you can either write `List<ArrayList<Integer>> cc = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>()` where your generic type `ArrayList<Integer>` has to be same.

Comment: How about this `List<List<Integer>> listList = new ArrayList<>(arrayLists);`

Comment: Can you show some code? An ArrayList is already a List.

Comment: @Thilo an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` is not a `List<List<Integer>>`

Comment: @Ferrybig. That is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be best to share the code where you have this issue. However, you should declare the variables as `List<List<Integer>>`, and then instantiate using an `ArrayList`.

For example:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{

   List<List<Integer>> myValues = getValues();
   System.out.println(myValues);

}

public static List<List<Integer>> getValues() {
   List<List<Integer>> lst = new ArrayList<>();
   List<Integer> vals = new ArrayList<>();

   vals.add(1);
   vals.add(2);
   lst.add(vals);

   vals = new ArrayList<>();
   vals.add(5);
   vals.add(6);
   lst.add(vals);       

   return lst;
}
```

In general, [program to an interface (such as `List`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface).

Based upon the edit to the OP's question, one can see that, as originally suggested, one can change:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> ansList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

to

```
List<List<Integer>> ansList = new ArrayList<>();
```

And

```
 ArrayList<Integer> tempList = null;
```

to

```
List<Integer> tempList = null;
```

And the code will then conform to the method's return signature of `List<List<Integer>>`.